# Sharepoint 2019 on-premises authentication against external sso provider (SAML1.0 or OIDC 1.0)

Tags: sharepoint-on-prem, authentication, 2019, saml, openid-connect-protocol

We have to authenticate Sharepoint 2019 on-premise users against an external oidc provider which provides OpenID Connect 1.0 and SAML 2.0. As far i know Sharepoint 2019 doesn't support OIDC and only SAML1.0 so we're thinking of using IdentityServer4 as a gateway. something like -> Sharepoint talks to IdentityServer via WS-Federation / SAML 1.0 and IdentityServer acts as gateway and redirects internally to the external oidc provider. Is that possible? Or are there other possibilities to achieve this? Thanks

Comment: I hope you have found the solution. Anyway, MS have released SharePoint subscription edition which support OIDC: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/security-for-sharepoint-server/oidc-1-0-authentication